# Circle CI replace appsettings.json

Tags: circleci

I am starting to look at Circle CI to build my projects. At the moment we are using octopus deploy, but want to use something new.
Today we have a appsettings file eg. "Appsettings.json"

Here we have structure eg:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DatabaseConnectionString": "MyLocalConnectionString",
  "MessageBusConnectionString": "MyLocalConnectionString2"
},
"MessageBus": {
  "Sqs": {
    "DefaultQueu" : "LocalTestQueu",
    "ErrorQueu": "LocalErrorQueu"
  }
},
...
```

I want to replace all values with new ones.
Eg: DefaultQueu is the name of the key and I want LocalTestQueu value to be changed to "MyProductionQueu"

For example key in CircleCi would be something like:
MessageBus.Sqs.DefaultQueu = MyProductionQueu
and
ConnectionStrings.DatabaseConnectionString = MyProductionDatabaseConnectionString

How would I do that?

I know there is environment variables where I can do something like:
   "DatabaseConnectionString": "$MyConnectionString"

where simply string replace $MyConnectionString with the real connection string. But that is not what I am looking for.
We have all our local connectionstrings stored in source control. So we need key / value replacement as described as before.

Octopus let's us do something like this:
[image: Octopus]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for this at the moment.